# Xamarin Android: When I open my application by notification splash-screen doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, splash-screen

If I open the application by clicking on the notification (got from Google Cloud Messaging), I doesn't get splash-screen

### GcmListenerService.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Gcm;
using Android.Util;
using System;
using Android.Database.Sqlite;

namespace Dharma.Droid
{
[Service (Exported = false), IntentFilter (new [] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
public class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived (string from, Bundle data)
    {
        var message = data.GetString ("message");
        Log.Debug ("MyGcmListenerService", "From:    " + from);
        Log.Debug ("MyGcmListenerService", "Message: " + message);
        DataAccess.InsertDowload (message);
        SendNotification (message);
    }

    void SendNotification (string message)
    {
        var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder (this)
            .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.mhu2)
            .SetContentTitle ("Mobile Health Unit")
            .SetContentText ("U heeft een nieuwe vragenlijst.")
            .SetAutoCancel (true)
            .SetContentIntent (pendingIntent);

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify (0, notificationBuilder.Build());

    }
}
}
```

### InstanceIdListenerService.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Gcm.Iid;

namespace Dharma.Droid
{
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" })]
class MyInstanceIDListenerService : InstanceIDListenerService
{
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var intent = new Intent (this, typeof (RegistrationIntentService));
        StartService (intent);
    }
}
}
```

### RegistrationIntentService.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Gms.Gcm;
using Android.Gms.Gcm.Iid;

namespace Dharma.Droid
{
[Service(Exported = false)]
class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
{
    static object locker = new object();

    public RegistrationIntentService() : base("RegistrationIntentService") { }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent (Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info ("RegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken");
            lock (locker)
            {
                var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance (this);
                var token = instanceID.GetToken (
                    "***************", GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

                Log.Info ("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
                SendRegistrationToAppServer (token);
                Subscribe (token);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug("RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to get a registration token");
            return;
        }
    }

    void SendRegistrationToAppServer (string token)
    {

    }

    void Subscribe (string token)
    {
        var pubSub = GcmPubSub.GetInstance(this);
        pubSub.Subscribe(token, "/topics/global", null);
    }   
}
}
```

### SplashActivity.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Util;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Gms.Common;

namespace Dharma.Droid
{
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]      
public class SplashActivity :  AppCompatActivity
{
    static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof (SplashActivity).Name;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        Task startupWork = new Task(() =>
            {
                Task.Delay(5000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.
            });

        startupWork.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                NetworkDiscovery network = new NetworkDiscovery();
                CredentialsService cs = new CredentialsService();

                if (GetToken() && network.IsOnline()) 
                {
                    StartActivity(typeof (MainActivity));
                } 
                else
                {
                    StartActivity(typeof (NoInternetActivity)); 
                }

            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        startupWork.Start();
    }

    public bool GetToken() 
    {
        if (IsPlayServicesAvailable ())
        {
            var intent = new Intent (this, typeof (RegistrationIntentService));
            StartService (intent);
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;   
        }
    }

    public bool IsPlayServicesAvailable ()
    {
        int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.IsGooglePlayServicesAvailable (this);

        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.Success)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with these lines:

```
var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
```

Specifically `var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));` where you are telling the notification to open your `MainActivity` when it is clicked. If you want to show the splash screen, you should tell it to open the splash screen instead by replacing that line with:

```
var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(SplashActivity));
```

The only issue with this is if the application is already open, you might not want to show the splash screen again. To fix this, I would recommend doing something like [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/50b5896e17b86d88df53175fea5f4b1fa99b1164/Sport.Android/MainActivity.cs#L20) where they have a `boolean` on `IsRunning` that gets set in the `MainActivity` lifecycle events. You could check that `boolean` like this possibly:

```
Activity intent;

if(MainActivity.IsRunning) {
    intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MainActivity));
    intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
} else {
    intent = new Intent (this, typeof(SplashActivity));
    intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
}

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
```

Warning, I did not test the code above.

Comment: There will be problem when notification is sent while app is running, and notification being clicked while app is in background or killed. In this case, MainActivity will be opened when app is in background.